# $T4 does not have a member named Generator ERROR swift

Tags: swift, ibaction

```
  @IBAction func button(sender : AnyObject) {
    var videoConnection : AVCaptureConnection!
    videoConnection = nil
    var connection : AVCaptureConnection
    var port : AVCaptureInputPort
    var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

    for connection in stillImageOutput?.connections{ //this line is where the error is

 }
```

}

I am trying to take a picture with my custom camera and I am getting this error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`stillImageOutput` is an optional - even if you are using optional chaining, it cannot be used in a `for` loop, because if `stillImageOutput` is nil, the statement would be:

```
for connection in nil {
}
```

which wouldn't make sense.

To fix it, you have to use optional binding:

```
if let connections = x?.connections {
    for connection in connections {

    }
}
```

Comment: @Antonio, thanks for the idea of substituting "nil" for the variable as a way to sanity check code that uses optionals!

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing Antonio's answer, if you are **100% sure** that in a specific part of the code your optional is not `nil`, you can just use the `!` directly in your `var`, to avoid the `if let` check.

```
for connection in stillImageOutput!.connections {

}
```